# How to append, and change properties of appended number (in css)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, append

I have two questions.

1. Mouseover on each Tag should change color of that tag to yellow
2. I should append random number to - Slucajan broj - (random is "broj"). Problem is: random number should be bigger than the rest, and color red.

Everything that I tried, it looks to me that JS is not accepting anything after `replaceWith` line. There is no error, but I don't know where is my mistake.

This is the code:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <title> Jquery</title>
</head>

<body>

  <style>
    .obojeno= {
      color: red;
      size: 1.55em
    }
  </style>

  <input type="text" name="prvi" id="prvi" value="Tag"></input>

  <button type="button" id="ponisti" name="ponistavanje">Poništi</button>
  <div class="prikazati"><br></div>
  <hr>
  <form id="unesi" action="#">

    <input type="number" id="min" placeholder="min"></input>
    <input type="number" id="max" placeholder="max"></input>
    <button type="button" id="generisanje" name="generisi">Generiši</button>


    <p id="slu"><b>Slucajan broj </b></p>
  </form>
  <script>
    $('#slu').append('<b>[0-10]:</b>');

    var brojac = 1;
    var kopirati = $(`<div class="prikazati"></div>`);
    $('#prvi').on('input', function(e) {
      if (e.target.value === ' ') {
        kopirati.clone().insertAfter('#ponisti').append('Tag' + brojac);
        $('#prvi').val('');
        brojac += 1;
      }
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.prikazati', function() {
      $(this).remove();
    });

    $('#ponisti').click(function() {
      $('.prikazati').html('<br>');
      brojac = 1;
    });

    $('#generisanje').click(function() {
      var don = Number(document.getElementById('min').value);
      var gor = Number(document.getElementById('max').value);
      var broj;
      broj = (Math.round(Math.random() * (gor - don + 1)) + don);
      //   $('#slu').replaceWith('<br> <br> Slucajan broj','['+ don + ' - ' + gor + ']: ');
      $('#slu').each(function() {
        var elemSlu = $(this);
        elemSlu.replaceWith('<br> <br> Slucajan broj', '[' + don + ' - ' + gor + ']: ');
        $('#slu').append(broj);
      });
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Not answering the questions, but: Your css style is invalid, remove `=` between class selector and `{`

Comment: Also, the CSS class obojeno isn't attached to anything, so if that's the class for the random number, you will need to fix that.  However, the big problem here is with your replaceWith.  It is doing the job, but the job that isn't doing is replacing the #slu element with the new content, so when it comes down to the line where you're appending to the #slu element, it doesn't work because you've replaced that element so it's not there anymore, so the code does nothing.  You need to redo what you're trying to do in that $('#slu').each function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you try to select the element you just replaced, after you call `replaceWith` the element `#slu` no longer exists in your page. You could instead of replacing the whole element, just replace the inner html of the element with

```
 elemSlu.html('<br> <br> Slucajan broj', '[' + don + ' - ' + gor + ']: ');
```

and then append your number to that (in jquery you can chain these operations)

```
elemSlu.html('Slucajan broj [' + don + ' - ' + gor + ']:').append(broj);
```

Side note:

An id is unqiue. There should always only be 1 element with the id ´slu´ on your page so something like this:

```
    $('#slu').each(function() {
      var elemSlu = $(this);
      elemSlu.replaceWith('<br> <br> Slucajan broj', '[' + don + ' - ' + gor + ']: ');
      $('#slu').append(broj);
    });
```

Does not make sense and gets as simple as :

```
$('#slu').html('Slucajan broj [' + don + ' - ' + gor + ']:').append(broj);
```

Answer (score 1):

First,

```js
elemSlu.replaceWith('<br> <br> Slucajan broj', '[' + don + ' - ' + gor + ']: ');
```

It replaces your `<p id="slu">` with `<br><br>...`. So then next time when you try to replace the content, the selector `$('#slu')` wont find anything and will be ignored.

I think you should use `elemSlu.html()` instead:

```js
elemSlu.html('<br> <br> Slucajan broj [' + don + ' - ' + gor + ']: ');
```

Also your style `.obojeno` has to be applied to the appended `broj`. Something like this would work:

```js
$('#slu').append(`<span class="obojeno">${broj}</span>`);
```

and the style `.obojeno` should look like this:

```css
.obojeno {
  color: red;
  font-size: 1.55em;
}
```

**and** also concerning the 'Tag'. I'm not sure which tags do you mean?.. Though anyway you could use a css selector `hover` to style them.. If the 'tags' is your text input (with value 'Tag'), then the css could look like this:

```css
input[type='text']:hover {
  background-color: yellow
}
```

**edit** because of your comment, the style for Tags would look like this:

```css
.prikazati:hover { 
   background: yellow; 
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <title> Jquery</title>
</head>

<body>
  <style>
    .obojeno {
      color: red;
      font-size: 1.55em;
    }
    input[type='text']:hover {
      background-color: yellow
    }
   .prikazati:hover { 
      background: yellow; 
    }
  </style>
  <input type="text" name="prvi" id="prvi" value="Tag">

  <button type="button" id="ponisti" name="ponistavanje">Poništi</button>
  <div class="prikazati"><br></div>
  <hr>
  <form id="unesi" action="#">

    <input type="number" id="min" placeholder="min">
    <input type="number" id="max" placeholder="max">
    <button type="button" id="generisanje" name="generisi">Generiši</button>


    <p id="slu"><b>Slucajan broj </b></p>
  </form>
  <script>
    $('#slu').append('<b>[0-10]:</b>');

    var brojac = 1;
    var kopirati = $(`<div class="prikazati"></div>`);
    $('#prvi').on('input', function(e) {
      if (e.target.value === ' ') {
        kopirati.clone().insertAfter('#ponisti').append('Tag' + brojac);
        $('#prvi').val('');
        brojac += 1;
      }
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.prikazati', function() {
      $(this).remove();
    });

    $('#ponisti').click(function() {
      $('.prikazati').html('<br>');
      brojac = 1;
    });

    $('#generisanje').click(function() {
      var don = Number(document.getElementById('min').value);
      var gor = Number(document.getElementById('max').value);
      var broj;
      broj = (Math.round(Math.random() * (gor - don + 1)) + don);
      //   $('#slu').replaceWith('<br> <br> Slucajan broj','['+ don + ' - ' + gor + ']: ');
      $('#slu').each(function() {
        var elemSlu = $(this);
        elemSlu.html('<br> <br> Slucajan broj [' + don + ' - ' + gor + ']: ');
        $('#slu').append(`<span class="obojeno">${broj}</span>`);
      });
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. When you press "space" in the first input field, for each space, one tag is forming. Hover on individual Tag should make that tag change it's color.

Comment: ah ok.. then `.prikazati:hover { background: yellow; }`

Comment: Tried with html, but without sucess. I got "Slucajan broj" as replacement. No any other number.

Comment: Tried with elemSlu.html('<br> <br> Slucajan broj [' + don + ' - ' + gor + ']: ');

Comment: Have you checked my code snippet? There it works.. just copy&past the code from there..?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't checked. It works. Is there any other way to select just "Tag", not the whole row ? Thank you very, very much.

Comment: Actually you don't need this `.append()` part at all. You can just use .html() like this: $('#slu').html('<br> <br> Slucajan broj [' + don + ' - ' + gor + ']: <span class="obojeno">' + broj + '</span> ');` and that's it..

Comment: about the Tag.. you can append a `span` to your `kopirati.clone` like this:  `kopirati.clone().insertAfter('#ponisti').append('<span>Tag' + brojac +'</span>')... And then the style would be like: `.prikazati span:hover { background: yellow; }` .. And if you find this answer helpful don't forget to accepted it as correct ;) good luck

Comment: In order to avoid opening new topic, external JS is not working. It seems that it's loaded. But it behaves like it's not. No errors. I coped your code to external file.

Comment: do you load it in the `html` `head`? you have to probably load it just before your closing body tag.. otherwise `html` would not be ready by the time the script will be executed..